# Install AMDGPU-PRO for AMD R9 390

Tags: amd-graphics-card

how can I use the AMDGPU-PRO driver for my R9 390? Currently it is using Radeon and I want to switch.

I already tried to blacklist raedon with:

`touch /etc/modprobe.d/radeon.conf`

Then added in the file:

`blacklist radeon`

Afterwards:

`sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo reboot`

Answer (score 0):

https://forum.level1techs.com/t/r9-390-ubuntu-17-04-amd-gpu-support/117034/5?u=kuramathecrimsonfox

Pretty well, you have to blacklist it in grub before you boot. This can be done with the grub configuration file. 
Had the same problem a bit back. Infact, this forum link is me asking for help, and the final solution I got.